# How to hard code a select list from a value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my edit page using EditorFor to edit the value of location.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , id = "testing" } })
```

But I would like to make that value edit come from a hard code list like below.

How can I make it that it defaults to the correct value and be able to select the other options.

```
 var selectLocation = new SelectList(
     new List<SelectListItem>
     {

            new SelectListItem {Text = "State", Value = "State"},
             new SelectListItem {Text = "International", Value = "International"},
              new SelectListItem {Text = "test2", Value = "test2"},
     }, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: Why not using `Html.DropDownListFor` razor helper instead of `Html.EditorFor`?

Comment: @zed no, im new to asp.net and after i created the view that what it created the EditorFor

Answer (score 2):

The `@Html.EditorFor()` helper used to generate `<input>` elements, not a `<select>` element. You should use a property with type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` on the viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string location { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

And assign it inside controller action method like this:

```
var model = new ViewModel();

var selectLocation = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem {Text = "State", Value = "State"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "International", Value = "International"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "test2", Value = "test2"},
};

model.Locations = selectLocation;

// return the view with existing viewmodel
return View(model);
```

Then, use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper to generate `<select>` element with options list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.location, Model.Locations, ...)
```

**Note:**

1) If you're already created `List<SelectListItem>` object, no need to convert it into `SelectList` object, because `SelectList` also has `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` type for the option list.

2) Alternatively you can use `ViewBag` to pass the `List<SelectListItem>` object, but the approach above is mostly used for strongly-typed option list.

Comment: Thank you, but i dont think this uses the default value location for the edit.